# Pass by references?

Tags: c++

In the code below, I do not understand the difference between the two versions. In both cases, I make a passage by reference, it seems to me (I think).

Moreover, I do not understand why version 2 works, because for what I understand for the moment, the sign `&` allows me to give the address of a variable, so when I put `function_name(int &yourInt)` I technically ask the user to enter the address of an `int`? So I should call it like `function_name(&myInt)`? But here we call the function like `function_name(myInt)` instead.

Version 1 :

```cpp
int value(int tab[], int *valeur)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *valeur += tab[i];
    }
    return *valeur;
}

int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    int tab[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << value(tab, &test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Version 2 :

```cpp
int value(int tab[], int &valeur)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        valeur += tab[i];
    }
    return valeur;
}

int main()
{
    int test = 0;
    int tab[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << value(tab, test) << std::endl;
    std::cout << test;
}
```

Comment: The first program uses a pointer rather than a reference. References and pointers are different things, but some programs (like yours) can be written equally well with references and pointers.

Answer (score 1):

When the `&` character is part of a type declaration, it means that variable is a `reference` to another. So in the second function, `int &valeur` declares a variable named `valeur` that is a reference to an `int`. This example should help you understand:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int a = 5;
  int& b = a; // b is a reference to a
  std::cout << a << '\n'; // outputs 5
  std::cout << b << '\n'; // outputs 5
  a = 7;
  std::cout << a << '\n'; // outputs 7
  std::cout << b << '\n'; // outputs 7
}
```

As a result, you can simply call your second function with `value(tab, test)` which passes the `test` variable by reference.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `value` takes a pointer to int as second parameter. A pointer is used to save a memory address, so the function has to be called using the address operator (`&`), passing the address of `test`.

In the second example, `value` takes a non-const reference to int as second parameter, so you do not need to pass the memory address of `test` this time. What happens is almost equivalent to something like this:

```
int test = 0;
int& valeur = test;
```

So **remember**, the address operator:

```
int test;
std::cout << &test; // outputs address of "test" in memory
```

is not the same as a reference, which is part of the type of a variable:

```
int test;
int& valeur = test; // here, the type of "valeur" is "int&"
```